# Search for an item with a common ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<div>
    <div><!-- all div without ID -->
        <span>some text</span>
        <div>
          <span id="listener1">click here</span>
          <span>sometext</span></div>
        <div>

        <span class="FIND_ME">Result Here</span></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>some text</span>
        <div id="div1">
         <div id="div2">
          <span id="listener2">click here</span>
          <span>sometext</span></div>
         </div>
        <div>

        <span class="FIND_ME">Result Here</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should be the following logic: wheen I click on "click here" the element with class "FIND_ME" should hide, which is the nearest common ancestor with the button pressed. Is it possible to do this?

```
$("#listener1").click(function(){
    $(this).<SUPER_SEARCHING>.hide(); // for example hide, or add some CSS class
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find closest div that has element `.find_me` in it:

```
$("#listener1").click(function(){
   $(this).closest('div:has(.FIND_ME)').find('.FIND_ME').hide();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4xhr9dx/)**