# jQuery's closest doesn't work in IE8/9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(this).closest('div:has(.FIND_ME)').find('.FIND_ME').hide();
```

But element with class `.FIND_ME` doesn't hide in IE8 and 9.

This question is a continuation of [Search for an item with a common ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027305/search-for-an-item-with-a-common-ancestor)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div><!-- all div without ID -->
        <span>some text</span>
        <div>
          <span id="listener1">click here</span>
          <span>sometext</span></div>
        <div>

        <span class="FIND_ME">Result Here</span></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>some text</span>
        <div id="div1">
         <div id="div2">
          <span id="listener2">click here</span>
          <span>sometext</span></div>
         </div>
        <div>

        <span class="FIND_ME">Result Here</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And it works in all other browsers ?

Comment: I can guarantee you that `closest()` works fine in IE8/9. The issue will lie in your code somewhere. Please add your relevant HTML to the question.

Comment: I seriously doubt such a "simple" thing would not be cross-browser... Here's a tip : 99% of the time, the issue is not jQuery but the way you use it, always try to figure out what you did wrong instead of blaming jQuery, you'll end up sparing a lot of time.

Comment: It works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/h34L271a/ Check the console for errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Also, what jquery version?

Comment: try as $(this).parent("div").next("span.FIND_ME").hide();

Comment: Note that classnames are case sensitive, you should generally stick with lowercase.

Comment: are you using Jquery 2.x in your project? It does not support IE8.

Comment: It seems that this has already been reported [https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/795121/jquerys-closest-method-fails-sporadically](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/795121/jquerys-closest-method-fails-sporadically)

Answer (score 15):

I was setting a variable `element` to `this`, then later on I was calling:

```
element.closest('a')
```

But element was now the DOM element instead of the jQuery object. So changing to:

```
$(element).closest('a')
```

fixed it.

Comment: This doesn't work in IE 11, even if it is a Jquery object, it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
closest = function (target, tag) {
    if (target.parentElement == "undefined") {
        return null;
    }
    if (target.parentElement.localName == tag) {
        return target.parentElement;
    }
    return this.closest(target.parentElement, tag);
};
```

Comment: Would you please add some explanation why this aswers the question and is what it says more than other answers?

Answer (score 0):

You're right! I don't know why, but it works now! The mistake was in an another place.

Thus, `closest()` works fine in IE 8/9. Tested on jQuery 1.6.